# How to delete user data (any data) from Firebase Cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When using firebase cloud functions, I encountered the following problem when a user deletes his account, I need to delete his data from the Firebase database (I know this can be done on the client side, and before that I did so), but now as a Start to use the cloud functions, I decided to do this case. In the function logs, I see the error of the following type "TypeError: admin.database.ref is not a function", please tell me how it can be fixed?

My function

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


    // deleting functions 
    exports.userDidDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
        const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

        const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
        const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.
        const userSearchLocationModelPath = '/userSearchLocationModel/' + user.uid;
        admin.database.ref(userSearchLocationModelPath).remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
admin.database.ref(userSearchLocationModelPath).remove();
```

to this:

```
admin.database().ref(userSearchLocationModelPath).remove();
```